# Online calculator for solving Sylvester matrix equations

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

So for my term paper in programming, I was assigned to write a program that would solve [Sylvester matrix equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation) for $X$ $$AX - XB = C$$ where $X$, $A$, $B$, and $C$ are all square matrices of the same size.

The process of solving them by hand is pretty long and tedious, and I don't want to deal with it, but I have no other way of checking my work. I've tried to find an online calculator that could solve this type of equations, but thus far to no avail. So if anyone knows of one - or any other approach that would allow me to skip doing it by hand - I will be very grateful, thanks :)

Comment: Suppose you have found a numerical matrix $X$, checking whether it's right should be easy by computing the LHS and RHS, then checking for equality to some small numerical margin?

Comment: I thought the [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation) was $AX+XB=C$ or $AX-XB=C$ with the difficulty coming from pre- and post-multiplication.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation) has some links to solvers

Comment: @Henry oh yeah, my bad.... Thanks!

Comment: @James damn, how did I not think of that... thx

Comment: There should be math libraries that can do the matrix multiplication and complex number parts instantly, so you shouldn't need to do much work on those algebra codes :)

Comment: Do you know who to solve a linear system $A x = b$?

Comment: Install [Julia](https://julialang.org/downloads/) on your local machine. It has a built-in `sylvester()` function which solves this kind of equation.